# Converting a dataframe column to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframes called `historic_price` with two columns called `'price'` and `'item'` that I am trying to multiple together storing the result in a different data-frame called `dayData`, but I get the exception:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The `'price'` column looks like:

```
           price
0        5.86500
1        2.03000
2       13.55000
3      639.75450
4      343.94325
5     1009.43500
6      585.60600
7     2208.72400
8      807.54800
9      236.51530
10      14.34000
```

The `'item'` column looks like:

```
     item
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
```

(I know all of the values are zero but even so when I multiple price by item I shoud still get a result (0))

the data types for the two columns are both `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

I am trying to add the product of item and price to the `dayData` dataframe as follows:

```
dayData["cash"]  =  historicPrice["price"]  * historicPrice["item"]
```

but I get the exception above.

I have tried converting the columns to float:

```
dayData["cash"]  =  float(historicPrice["price"])  * float(historicPrice["item"])
```

but with no luck (I get the exception: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`)

Can anyone let me know what i need to do to fix please?

Many thanks

Comment: what is the result of `historicPrice.dtypes`?

Comment: you need to convert the dtypes try `df=df.astype(float)` first

Comment: dtype: object, I tried historicPower=historicPower.astype(float) but got the exception:TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when i then tried multiplying the columns together

Comment: @Stacey there should be ouptut for each of your columns when you do `historicPower.dtypes`

Comment: @Stacey I think the issue is that one of your columns is storing the values as strings. However, when you use `historicPower=historicPower.astype(float)` that should be fixed! After you do that, can you show the results of `type(historicPower['price'][0]),type(historicPower['item'][0])`

Comment: @Stacey  Please include .. historicPrice.info() to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's highly likely you have strings in one of the columns. Try using to_numeric with errors set to 'coerce':

```
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['item'] = pd.to_numeric(df['item'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)

df['cash'] = df['price'] * df['item']
```